# topological dual for $C_c(\Bbb{R})$ and $C_0(\Bbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $C_c(\Bbb{R})$ and $C_0(\Bbb{R})$ equipped with supermum norm.Then we know uniform closure of $C_c(\Bbb{R})$ is $C_0(\Bbb{R})$.

I also know the following version of Riesz representation theorem:

> For locally compact Hasudorff space (here is $\Bbb{R}$) topological dual $C_0(X)$ is set of finite Radon measure.

I don't know how to deduce the following Reisz representation theorem for $C_c(\Bbb{R})$

> linear functional $\lambda$ over $C_c(\Bbb{R})$ is Radon measure if and only if for any $K$ compact set,exist some $M$ such that $$|\lambda(\phi)|\le M \sup_{x\in K}|\phi(x)|$$ ( this seems to state that Radon measure is topological dual of continuous function with compact supported equipped with LF topology?)

Can we do it based on the first one?Here are 2 question :

- How to deduce the second version of representation theorem
- What about topological dual of $C_c(\Bbb{R})$ with sup norm instead of LF topology?

Comment: Since the completion of $C_c$ with sup-norm is $C_0$ you have that $C_c^* = C_0^*$. For the other $C_c$ topology your previous theorem gives you now for each compactum $K$ a finite radon measure with the property that if $K\subseteq K'$ then the restriction to $K$ of the measure associated to $K'$ agrees with the measure of $K$. With local compactness you can nicely glue that stuff together to get a measure on all of $X$ - check that the three properties of a Radon measure remain satisfied.

Comment: thanks,I got it,the equality $C_c^* = C_0^*$ due to denseness result and Hahn Banach extension theorem correct?

Comment: Hahn Banach is not necessary (in fact you cannot apply it since $C_c$ is not closed). Instead note that (sup-norm continuous) linear functionals on $C_c$ are necessary Lipschitz maps $C_c\to\Bbb C$ which then extend uniquely to the completion of $C_c$.

Comment: For the second point do you mean since for $X = \bigcup K_i$ we have the result that: $\ell$ continuous on $C_c(X)$ with LF topology, is exactly for each $\ell|_{C_c(K_i)} : C_c(K_i)\to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous then it must be some finite Radon measure on $K_i$,denote it $\mu_{K_i}$ then to glue it together we can define a measure on $X$ (denote it $\mu$) as given any $E\subset X$ since exist $E\subset K_i$ for some $K_i$ then defined it as $\mu(E) = \mu_{K_i}(E)$ correct?

Comment: @s.harp for the first point I use the theorem that bounded linear function on some subspace (need not to be closed) can always be extended to the whole space that preseve norm,to prove this use the analytic form Hahn Banach theorem which does not need the subspace to be closed ? (the first version in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem)

Comment: $E\subset K_i$ is not guaranteed but that is roughly the idea of the gluing. You can for example define $\mu(E):=\sup_{K\subseteq E}\mu_K(K)$ - but you will have to check all the details of Radon measure.

Comment: very thanks,I got it @s.harp